# Question regarding RMM setup

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

I have configured a domain through SAP to my marketing cloud instance. I'd like to configure RMM now but I have some questions:

After I configure RMM will I be able to reconfigure it in case I want to change something like the "Forward email address", "Email display name" and "Email Reply Address"?

For my "Reply Subdomain" do I just insert the subdomain I configure for SAP with "reply." in front of it?

Can I reconfigure my custom response?